# storing text into string buffer from multiple files using python

Tags: python, file, io, glob

I want to extract text from multiple text files and the idea is that i have a folder and all text files are there in that folder.

I have tried and succesfully get the text but the thing is that when i use that string buffer somewhere else then only first text file text are visbile to me.

I want to store these texts to a particular string buffer.

what i have done:

```html
import glob
import io

Raw_txt = " "
files = [file for file in glob.glob(r'C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\RAW\\*.txt')]
for file_name in files:
    
    with io.open(file_name, 'r') as image_file:
        content1 = image_file.read()
        Raw_txt = content1
        print(Raw_txt)
```

This Raw_txt buffer only works in this loop but i want this buffer somewhere else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is related to where you load the content of your text files.
`Raw_txt` is overwritten with each file.
I would recommend you to do something like this where the text is appended:

```py
import glob

Raw_txt = ""
files = [file for file in glob.glob(r'C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\RAW\\*.txt')]
for file_name in files:
    with open(file_name,"r+") as file:
        Raw_txt += file.read() + "\n" # I added a new line in case you want to separate the different text content of each file
print(Raw_txt)
```

Also in order to read a text file you don't need `io` module.